# Office Js: avoid doubling "&" symbol on ribbon button tooltip

Tags: ms-word, office-js, manifest, office-addins, word-addins

I am developing a Word addin with Office-js. I want to create a button in my ribbon. This button's name and tooltip should be `AAA & BBB`.

So, I developed the following part of the xml manifest.

```
<Group id="XXX.GrpYYY">
   <Label resid="XXX.GrpYYY.Label"/>
   <Icon>...</Icon>
   <Control xsi:type="Button" id="XXX.BtnYYY">
      <Label resid="XXX.BtnYYY.Label" />
      <Supertip>
         <Title resid="XXX.BtnYYY.Label" />
         <Description resid="XXX.BtnYYY.Tooltip" />
      </Supertip>
      <Icon>...</Icon>
      <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
         <SourceLocation resid="XXX.YYY.SL" />
      </Action>
   </Control>
</Group>
```

And this is the relevant part of the Resources in the xml manifest:

```
<bt:ShortStrings>
   ...
   <bt:String id="XXX.GrpYYY.Label" DefaultValue="MY GROUP" />
   ...
   <bt:String id="XXX.BtnYYY.Label" DefaultValue="AAA &amp; BBB" />
   ...
</bt:ShortStrings>
<bt:LongStrings>
   ...
   <bt:String id="XXX.BtnYYY.Tooltip" DefaultValue="AAA &amp; BBB" />
   ...
</bt:LongStrings>
```

This is the result:

[image: My Ribbon Button]

As you can see the `&` symbol in the tooltip is doubled.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to avoid doubling this symbol?

Comment: That looks like a bug. You could raise it as an issue on the [office-js repo[(https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose). But first try using only "&" in the tooltip or only "amp;".

Comment: @RickKirkham only "&" is an illegal syntax in xml, and "amp;" will print "amp;"

Comment: I was afraid of that. I recommend that you create the issue in the repo.